# Check if time_t is zero

Tags: c, linux, timer, time-t

I have written a timer eventloop with epoll and the timerfd linux API. The magpage of `timerfd_gettime` states the following:

```
The it_value field returns the amount of time until the timer will
next expire.  If both fields of this structure are zero, then the
timer is currently disarmed.
```

So to check if a timer is currently armed or disarmed I had written the following code:

```
bool timer_is_running(struct timer *timer)
{
    struct itimerspec timerspec;

    if(timerfd_gettime(timer->_timer_fd, &timerspec) == -1) {
        printf("[TIMER] Could not  get timer '%s' running status\n", timer->name);
        return false;
    }

    printf("[TIMER] Checking running state of timer '%s' it_value.tv_sec = %"PRIu64", it_value.tv_nsec = %"PRIu64"\n", timer->name, (uint64_t) timerspec.it_value.tv_sec, (uint64_t) timerspec.it_value.tv_nsec == 0);
    return timerspec.it_value.tv_sec != 0  && timerspec.it_value.tv_nsec != 0;
}
```

This wasn't working and all timers were reported as disarmed. when I looked at the output I saw the following on a currently disarmed timer:

```
[TIMER] Checking running state of timer 'test' it_value.tv_sec = 0, it_value.tv_nsec = 4302591840
```

After further investigation it seems only the `tv_sec` field is set to 0 on disarmed timers.

This is program runs on kernel 3.18.23 on MIPS architecture (OpenWRT).

Before I flag this as a bug in the kernel implementation I would like to know if it's correct to check if a `time_t` is 0 by doing `time_t == 0`. Can anyone confirm this?

Kind regards,
Daan

Comment: Use `||` in the returned expression, not `&&`.

Comment: Did you intend the third argument to be `timerspec.it_value.tv_nsec == 0`? This will evaluate to `0` when the timer has a value. I ask, because that won't be a 64-bit value to match the format spec.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a bug in the kernel implementation.  It is your code that is flawed.

> The it_value field returns the amount of time until the timer will
>   next expire.  If both fields of this structure are zero, then the
>   timer is currently disarmed.

The converse of this is that (assuming the call `timerfd_gettime()` succeeds) the timer is armed if ONE or BOTH of the fields of the structure are non-zero.

The last return statement of your function is

```
return timerspec.it_value.tv_sec != 0  && timerspec.it_value.tv_nsec != 0;
```

which returns `true` only if BOTH the fields are non-zero.   Instead, you need to use

```
return timerspec.it_value.tv_sec != 0  || timerspec.it_value.tv_nsec != 0;
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It works now, I was also mislead because the printf statement in which I cast `time_t` to `uint64_t` was not working correctly.

Answer (score 3):

The [`time_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/time_t) type alias is an arithmetic or real type. Both arithmetic and real types can by implicitly compared with the integer value zero.

Furthermore, on POSIX systems (like Linux) `time_t` is defined as an *integer* (see e.g. [this `<sys/types.h>` reference](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sys_types.h.html)).

While the C standard doesn't explicitly specify the type of `time_t` just about all implementations use integers for `time_t` for compatibility reasons. I don't know any implementation where it's not an integer.

So the answer to your question is that the comparison is correct.

It should be noted that it's only the `tv_sec` member that is of type `time_t`. The `tv_nsec` member is a `long`.